# Replace all img tag with specific class before saving in the database?

Tags: php, regex

Example I have a img tag like this...

```
<img alt="INLINE:143246;w=240;h=240" class="wysiwyg-inline-image" src="/sites/default/files/styles/inline_image_temp_240x240/public/2013/05/30/600x600_30.png?itok=7mP9F2QH" />
```

I want it to be replaced by...

```
<p><!-- INLINE:143220;w=240;h=240 --></p>
```

before saving into the DB based on `img` alt attribute.

NOTE: The number of images is dynamic coz the user might upload multiple images in different sizes. The image size is on the image alt.

So far I have this code.

```
preg_match_all("/(<img[^>]+>)/i", $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], $matches);

foreach($matches as $match) {
  // Replace all matched elements here.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace it, then use preg_replace. Consider you got the string in $str variable, then following will be the way to do it using preg_replace.

`$str = preg_replace('/<img.*?alt="(.+?)".*?>/', '<p><!-- $1 --></p>', $str);`

Comment: Where's the `$1` came from? Does it treat the `$str` as array and the alt is in position 1?

Comment: $1 will contain the first matched string for the pattern. Yeah it will contain the alt value in this case.

Comment: You don't need to `preg_match_all` and do the loop, you just need to replace the code with `preg_replace`

Comment: Yeah your code works but it only generate a single output even I have a lot of images

Comment: Oh, I missed a question mark to avoid the greediness in regex. Replace the regular expression with `/<img.*?alt="(.+?)".*?>/`. Edited the answer also.

Comment: It will be better than matching all and doing the loop and then replace. Or else you have to parse html and do the replace. But in that case also it will take resources to parse the html. I think this the best approach.

Comment: Thanks dude...u really saved me from hundred of hours.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $html  = $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];  // saving value in a variable to manipulate
 preg_match_all("/(<img[^>]+>)/i", $html , $matches);  // returns all image tags

 foreach($matches as $match) {
    $str = preg_replace('/<img.*alt="(.+?)".*?>/', '<p><!-- $1 --></p>', $html);
     //  get the alt tag text
    $html = str_replace($mathch, $str, $html); replace in the original string
 }
 // save $html in database
```

Comment: I don't think you have to use preg_replace and str_replace at once. Wait.., you copied that line of preg_replace from my answer and thus your code will output an undefined $str variable warning as it is not used before the preg_replace line. Better change it to $html :-P

Comment: This one works if I only have one image but not if more than 1.

Comment: Thanks matey for your idea.